# OpenRAVE installation fails

Tags: ros, installation, openrave, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to try OpenRAVE together with ROS (Electric), but there is problem with installation.

When "rosdep install openrave_robot_control orrosplanning
openrave_sensors" is executed, i get this error:

```
Execution failed with OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install collada-dom
```

But collada-dom (libcollada15dom-dev) is installed in my system
(Ubuntu 11.04, x86_64).

When I try rosmake (instead of rosdep install...) it compiles for long
time with some warnings. But after successful compilation, I can't run
any demo... For example "roslaunch openrave_robot_control
schunkarm_sim.launch" gives me this error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type
[openrave_robot_control/simulationserver]: Cannot locate node of type
[simulationserver] in package [openrave_robot_control]
```

Is there any solution? Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11204/openrave-installation-fails/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openrave_robot_control  now compiles with ros electric

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thanks for the report! we just fixed it in jsk-ros-pkg r2172

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2011-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1